# Javascript works when loaded on browsers but not when i put it in codepen or jsfiddle?

Tags: javascript, css

Can anyone find out what this javascript isn't working? It works when i load it in chrome and firefox. I put it on codepen to show for a intern position but it's not working on codepen or  jsfiddle, not sure why.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/egpEG/

Comment: The link you provided does not contain anything.

Comment: You need to include jQuery

Comment: Oh, i just assumed it was included. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include jQuery to the fiddle or CodePen. You can add the following HTML code in your code pen:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, i just assumed it was included